# How can I have standard header/footers on part of an angular website?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

We are working on a site that has a public / protected area where the headers and footers are different.

```
/src
   /app
       app.module.ts
       app-routing.ts
       app.component
       /pub
           pub.component.ts
           pub-routing.module.ts
           pub.module.ts
           /aboutus
              aboutus.component.ts
       /priv
           priv.component.ts
           priv-routing.module.ts
           priv.module.ts
           /foo
              bar.component.ts
```

What I can't figure out is how to put a header / footer in pub.component.ts which is inherited by aboutus.component.ts.

If I navigate to /pub, the header and footer shows up, but going to /pub/aboutus only displays the content in that component.

```
-------------
pub.module.ts
-------------

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PubRoutingModule } from './pub-routing.module';
import { PubComponent } from './pub.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PubComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PubRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    PubRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class PubModule { }

---------------------
pub-routing.module.ts
---------------------

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PubComponent } from './pub.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './aboutus/aboutus.component';
const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pub', component: PubComponent },
  { path: 'pub/aboutus', component: AboutUsComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AboutUsComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(rootRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PubRoutingModule { }

----------------------
pub.component.ts
----------------------

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pub',
  template: `<p>Heading</p><router-outlet></router-outlet><p>Foot</p>`
})
export class PubComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `aboutus` part be a child route of `pub` for the `router-outlet` to show the content of the component while maintaining the header/footer from the parent component.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sxsgjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) - change the path to `/a/b` to test

Comment: Thank You!  Adding in the children: [{path: 'aboutus', component: AboutUsComponent}] to the pub path was the difference!  Three days of frustration were completed within 30 minutes.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: What is your favorite charity?

Comment: Sorry, don't really have one